# nested for loop even number print out

Tags: java, loops, nested

hello I am writing a code that will print even integers after the 10th number it will start on a new line so it will be 10 numbers per column and 10 rows. my code is printing all number but i want it to only print even numbers i tried to use an if statement but it does not seem to work please help. below is my code.

```
public static void mjj() {
    int s = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <=10;i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <=10;j++) {
            if (s % 2 == 0)
                System.out.print(s++ + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

i want it to print this

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40
```

and so on until the 10th row

Comment: Put your `if` statement back in so we can see what is wrong with it. At the moment there isn't even any attempt to just print evens. Having said that, you probably don't even need an `if`...

Comment: @John3136 I added it back with the if statement in the code prints nothing

Comment: HINT: you're not restricted to stepping your loop counter by 1 with `j++`; you could use `j+=2` or `j=j+2` to go in steps of 2.

Comment: How "s" is being incremented ? It starts from 1 and 1%2 !=0 so when ++s is executed in first place?

Comment: @johnmac the solution which you have is `O(10n)` which is worst for n number of rows printed. I have added an `O(n)` solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted code won't print anything since `s` never changes.
You can fix it by moving the increment of `s` before the `if`:

```
public static void mjj() {
    int s = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <=10;i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <=10;j++) {
            s++;  // <-- do it here
            if (s % 2 == 0)
                System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2 4 6 8 10 
12 14 16 18 20 
22 24 26 28 30 
32 34 36 38 40 
42 44 46 48 50 
52 54 56 58 60 
62 64 66 68 70 
72 74 76 78 80 
82 84 86 88 90 
92 94 96 98 100
```

If you want 10 numbers in each row, modify the for loops:

```
public static void mjj() {
    int s = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5;i++) { // up to 5
        for (int j = 1; j <=20; j++) { // up to 20
            s++;  // <-- do it here
            if (s % 2 == 0)
                System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Or make it a bit simpler:

```
public static void mjj() {
    for (int j = 2; j <=100; j += 2) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
        if (j % 20 == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 
42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 
62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 80 
82 84 86 88 90 92 94 96 98 100
```

Comment: OP wants 10 number in a column

Comment: still you think your solution is optimal ? For one outer loop the inner loop will execute 20 times.

Comment: this is what happening by looking at your solution

Comment: Yea that I got it, but still it's like `O(10n)` which is even more worst.

Comment: @Lokesh AFAIK  O(10n) == O(kn) == O(n)  where `k` is a constant.

Comment: So according to you the solution which you have given O(10n) and the solution which I have given O(n) are same ? Take a look at my answer . `O(10n) == O(kn) == O(n)` k won't be a constant if OP's condition changed let's say OP want the new line to print after 30 number in a row and having said that according to you O(30n) is same as O(10n) is same as O(n). I don't think so.

Comment: @Lokesh it's constant as long as it's not dynamically changing (e.g. parameter).

Answer (score 2):

I would change

```
if (s % 2 == 0)
    System.out.print(s++ + " ");
```

to

```
System.out.printf("%4d", (2 * s++));
```

which will format the `int` to four spaces and multiply each value by `2` (thus only showing even values). A small example of which is

```
   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20
 ...
 182 184 186 188 190 192 194 196 198 200
```

Comment: It cuts down the iterations to half.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're incrementing `s` in `System.out.print()`. I presume you surrounded this in the if statement you said you tried, and since `s` never met the condition, it never printed. Try something more like this:

```
int s = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10;i++) 
{
   for (int j = 1; j <= 10;j++) 
   {
      s++;
      if (s % 2 == 0)
      {
         System.out.print(s + " ");
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me , this is what I would change in your code.

```
public static void mjj() {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <=10;i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <=10;j++) {
            s= s + 2;
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: zero is an even number

Comment: Lol my apology for the careless mistake.

Probably can go with 

if (s%2 != 0)
    s = s++
System.out.print(s + " ")
s = s+2;

Comment: You can just print `s` before `adding 2 to s`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is `O(n)` solution for your problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++) {
            if(i%2==0) {
                System.out.print(i+" ");
            }
            count++;
            if(count%20==0)
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 
42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 
62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 80 
82 84 86 88 90 92 94 96 98 100
```

Comment: Nested loops do not automatically an `O(n^2)` solution make.  The original solution is at worst `O(10n)` for `n` the number of rows printed.

Comment: @KevinAnderson looking at the OP solution the inner loop will execute 10 times for one outer loop. That makes 100 times execution of inner loop for 10 outer loop

Comment: Yes, but if you double the number of steps of the outer loop,  the inner loop still only executes 10 times for each outer loop iteration, so the total number of steps only doubles instead of quadrupling.  So linear time complexity `O(10n)` in number of outer-loop iterations.  However, if both loops are tied to the same factor (i.e., if outer loop is doubled, inner loop always doubles too), then it does become `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void mjj() {
            int s = 2;
            for (int i = 1; i <=10;i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <=10;j++) {
                    if (s % 2 == 0){
                        System.out.print(s + " ");                      
                    }
                    s += 2;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    }
}
```

This will print out:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 
42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 
62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 80 
82 84 86 88 90 92 94 96 98 100 
102 104 106 108 110 112 114 116 118 120 
122 124 126 128 130 132 134 136 138 140 
142 144 146 148 150 152 154 156 158 160 
162 164 166 168 170 172 174 176 178 180 
182 184 186 188 190 192 194 196 198 200
```

Also, you can use printf for the better printout:

```
public static void mjj() {
    int s = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            if (s % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.printf("%3s ", s );
            }
            s += 2;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This will print out:

```
  2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20 
 22  24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38  40 
 42  44  46  48  50  52  54  56  58  60 
 62  64  66  68  70  72  74  76  78  80 
 82  84  86  88  90  92  94  96  98 100 
102 104 106 108 110 112 114 116 118 120 
122 124 126 128 130 132 134 136 138 140 
142 144 146 148 150 152 154 156 158 160 
162 164 166 168 170 172 174 176 178 180 
182 184 186 188 190 192 194 196 198 200
```